# TTFB (Time To First Byte) Really Long

Tags: mysql, performance, pagespeed

I'm loading a file on my web page with jQuery's [load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/) and it's taking upwards of 10 seconds to load. I understand that the PHP script that's being loaded is executing a query that's intensive and there are over 600k rows in the table that's being queried. But, in PHPMyAdmin, the query loads in about one second.

One other thing that may be responsible is that MySQL is configured to support remote login, meaning that the bind address is the IP address. From my understanding, that takes longer for the DNS lookup. But, I'm not sure. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing the logic in the 'GetHottest' API call and returning something simple such as an empty string just to test it? If the call returns quickly then it might be the logic, else if it is still slow then you can determine if it is related to the DNS....

Comment: Touching 600K rows is likely to take several seconds.  Let's see the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: If the web server is in Windows, keep in mind that the first byte won't come out until the entire page is built.